# Square Dagger: How to configure Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, installation, code-generation, dagger

How do I configure a Android Studio project to work with Square Dagger? I got it running in Eclipse but I absolutely don't know how to set up Android Studio for doing the annotation and code generation stuff.

Edit: my **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    apt
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.2"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.2"
    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
}

def getSourceSetName(variant) {
    return new File(variant.dirName).getName();
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def aptOutputDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/source/apt_generated    /${variant.dirName}")
    def aptOutput = new File(aptOutputDir, variant.dirName)
    println "****************************"
    println "variant: ${variant.name}"
    println "manifest:  ${variant.processResources.manifestFile}"
    println "aptOutput:  ${aptOutput}"
    println "****************************"

    android.sourceSets[getSourceSetName(variant)].java.srcDirs+= aptOutput.getPath()

    variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs += [
            '-processorpath', configurations.apt.getAsPath(),
            '-AandroidManifestFile=' + variant.processResources.manifestFile,
            '-s', aptOutput
    ]

    variant.javaCompile.source = variant.javaCompile.source.filter { p ->
        return !p.getPath().startsWith(aptOutputDir.getPath())
    }

    variant.javaCompile.doFirst {
        aptOutput.mkdirs()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following apt plugin - it works for us.

```
        com.jimdo.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.2-SNAPSHOT
```

In your buildscript repositories closure add

```
maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
```

and in the buildscript dependencies closure add

```
classpath 'com.jimdo.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.2-SNAPSHOT'
```

Then in your app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'apt'
```

You've already got the compile and apt dependencies for dagger in your apps dependencies closure so you should be good to go.  I'm not sure what the apt dependency on `org.androidannotations:android annotations:3.2` is for.  If you put it into support your apt solution you can probably take it out.